# How would I brute force my facebook account to which I have forgotten the password to without getting blocked by facebook from doing so?

Tags: python, facebook

Since, I have a hint to what the password could be I have sorted the password generation bit of the code. But how would I 'spam' the facebook form with the password without getting put on timeout or just 'spam' the facebook form while taking the timeouts.

```
import itertools
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = ['abc', 'cbe', 'adc', 'asda', 'asda']
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations(nums))
    a = []

    for permutation in permutations:
        a.append(''.join(permutation))
```

this is how far i have gotten,  i am planning to add all the possible passwords to a database and use that to spam the forms,  i am stuck on how to create the form submission bit of the code

Comment: show your attempt, provide a [mre], also you need to know how fb timeouts and perhaps, if the list is not that long, just do it manually (tho I feel like you will get timeouted even then at some point)?

Comment: @Matiiss here you go

Comment: I don't see you exactly attempting to post them anywhere (the first somewhat logical attempt should have been at least to do with `time.sleep`, `random.randint` and `requests.post`, which none of them you have tried) and that would still probably timeout you

Comment: @Matiiss I'll try to code the whole thing and will get back to you then

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rotating proxy to avoid IP bans, but I'm pretty sure there is an account wide timeout associated with logins, unless you have a small number of combinations it's not going to be sucessful.

So instead of that you could try reseting your password or writing them an email.

EDIT: If you really want to bruteforce it, a headless browser would be a good way. For python you have something like Selenium

Comment: I changed the email and password to this account when facebook didn't ask for verification for changing email, so my bumass typed a random email turns out its used by someone else and i have tried writing to facebook but you know their customer service